# Consuming a web service in an android application in localhost

Tags: android, web-services, netbeans-6.9

I am trying to consume a web service that I created locally from an Android application.
My problem is that in my Android app, at a certain point, I have to give an URL with parameters that looks like this : http://localhost:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService/add?i=1&j=1

where `CalculatorWS` is the web service I use, `add` is the operation in it and `i` and `j` are parameters of `add` operation. For now I am using a sample app Calculator (from NetBeans) for testing and I want to retrieve the correct URL to give to my web service client (Android app) so it can give me back an XML to parse.

I tried to use that URL mentioned above but it doesn't work.

Does anybody know what is the correct URL to put ?

Comment: Does your service listen on localhost interface?

Comment: i think that the problem isn't in the url that the android application consumes, if your web application on netbeans does the correct output to the inputstream (maybe writing a xml file) and you connect on android app i don't see a problem, maybe i don't understand your question

Comment: Does your service listen on localhost interface? Install a terminal on your Android device (if you haven't already), say `netstat -lnt` and see if anything lists 127.0.0.1.

Comment: @Franco : my problem is that I have a web service (JAX-WS in NetBeans EE6 platform) running normally in localhost and I want to consume it from an android application. Do you know how to proceed? @9000 : I don't have an android device right now, I will try to get one and try your command

Comment: @sharktiger i do the following, (always using the ip address that @Vikas and @MisterSquonk refers) connect with the server using java.net.HttpURLConnection and reading the response with the InputStream that java.net.HttpURLConnection provides me when i finish the write operation. Later i parse the buffers provided by InputStream and thats all, but i don't understand the nature of your question, if you can connect or cannot parse the data, if you cannot parse the data i'll post here my code

Comment: @Franco : my problem is simple : I can not connect so i can not parse data. So yes i think it would help me to see some code to know how to proceed with such problems. Thank u for your time.

Comment: ok, i paste some code in a new answer

Answer (score 5):

you need to set URL as 10.0.2.2:**portNr**

**portNr** = the given port by ASP.NET Development Server
my current service is running on 
localhost:3229/Service.svc

so my url is 10.0.2.2:3229

i'd fixed my problem this way

i hope it helps...

Answer (score 4):

Use this URL:

http://10.0.2.2:8080/CalculatorApp/CalculatorWSService/add?i=1&j=1

Since Android emulator run on Virtual Machine therefore we have to use this IP address instead of `localhost or 127.0.0.1`

Comment: I tried to run this at first :
http://10.0.2.2:8080/ but it always throws a call exception :(

Comment: @sharktiger: If you comment or reply use  at the rate (@) symbol followed by user name other wise it makes no sense. If you are getting any exception then post your error log here.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using an emulator then read below paragraph taken from: [Referring to localhost from the emulated environment](http://developer.android.com/guide/appendix/faq/commontasks.html#localhostalias)

> If you need to refer to your host computer's localhost, such as when
>   you want the emulator client to contact a server running on the same
>   host, use the alias 10.0.2.2 to refer to the host computer's loopback
>   interface. From the emulator's perspective, localhost (127.0.0.1)
>   refers to its own loopback interface.

Answer (score 0):

sharktiger like you says on the comments, i'll paste here some code to help you to figure how to proced, this code try to connect to a web service and parse the InputStream retrieved, just like @Vikas Patidar and @MisterSquonk says, you must configure the url in the android code like them explain. So, i post my code

and example of call to HttpUtils...

```
public static final String WS_BASE = "http://www.xxxxxx.com/dev/xxx/";
public static final String WS_STANDARD = WS_BASE + "webserviceoperations.php";
public static final String REQUEST_ENCODING = "iso-8859-1";

    /**
         * Send a request to the servers and retrieve InputStream
         * 
         * @throws AppException
         */
        public static Login logToServer(Login loginData) {
            Login result = new Login();
            try {
                // 1. Build XML
                byte[] xml = LoginDAO.generateXML(loginData);
                // 2. Connect to server and retrieve data
                InputStream is = HTTPUtils.readHTTPContents(WS_STANDARD, "POST", xml, REQUEST_ENCODING, null);
                // 3. Parse and get Bean
                result = LoginDAO.getFromXML(is, loginData);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                result.setStatus(new ConnectionStatus(GenericDAO.STATUS_ERROR, MessageConstants.MSG_ERROR_CONNECTION_UNKNOWN));

            }
            return result;
        }
```

and the method readHTTPContents from my class HTTPUtils

```
/**
     * Get the InputStream contents for a specific URL request, with parameters.
     * Uses POST. PLEASE NOTE: You should NOT use this method in the main
     * thread.
     * 
     * @param url
     *            is the URL to query
     * @param parameters
     *            is a Vector with instances of String containing the parameters
     */
    public static InputStream readHTTPContents(String url, String requestMethod, byte[] bodyData, String bodyEncoding, Map<String, String> parameters)
            throws AppException {
        HttpURLConnection connection = null;
        InputStream is = null;
        try {
            URL urlObj = new URL(url);
            if (urlObj.getProtocol().toLowerCase().equals("https")) {
                trustAllHosts();
                HttpsURLConnection https = (HttpsURLConnection) urlObj
                        .openConnection();
                https.setHostnameVerifier(new HostnameVerifier() {
                    public boolean verify(String hostname, SSLSession session) {
                        return true;
                    }
                });
                connection = https;
            } else {
                connection = (HttpURLConnection) urlObj.openConnection();
            }
            // Allow input
            connection.setDoInput(true);
            // If there's data, prepare to send.
            if (bodyData != null) {
                connection.setDoOutput(true);
            }
            // Write additional parameters if any
            if (parameters != null) {
                Iterator<String> i = parameters.keySet().iterator();
                while (i.hasNext()) {
                    String key = i.next();
                    connection.addRequestProperty(key, parameters.get(key));
                }
            }
            // Sets request method
            connection.setRequestMethod(requestMethod);
            // Establish connection
            connection.connect();
            // Send data if any

            if (bodyData != null) {
                OutputStream os = connection.getOutputStream();
                os.write(bodyData);
            }
            if (connection.getResponseCode() != HttpURLConnection.HTTP_OK) {
                throw new AppException("Error HTTP code " + connection.getResponseCode());
            }
            is = connection.getInputStream();
            int numBytes = is.available();
            if (numBytes <= 0) {
                closeInputStream(is);
                connection.disconnect();
                throw new AppException(MessageConstants.MSG_ERROR_CONNECTION_UNKNOWN);
            }

            ByteArrayOutputStream content = new ByteArrayOutputStream();

            // Read response into a buffered stream
            int readBytes = 0;
            while ((readBytes = is.read(sBuffer)) != -1) {
                content.write(sBuffer, 0, readBytes);
            }
            ByteArrayInputStream byteStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(content.toByteArray());
            content.flush();
            return byteStream;
        } catch (Exception e) {
//          Logger.logDebug(e.getMessage());
            throw new AppException(e.getMessage());
        } finally {
            closeInputStream(is);
            closeHttpConnection(connection);
        }
    }
```

Hope this help you...